# ThreadPoolExecutor vs threading.Thread

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, threadpoolexecutor

I've got a question regarding performance of `ThreadPoolExecutor` vs `Thread` class on its own which seems to me that I lack some fundamental understanding.

I've a web **scraper** in two functions. First to parse the links for each image of a website homepage and the second to load an image off the link parsed:

```
import threading
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import os
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

path = r'C:\Users\MyDocuments\Pythom\Networking\bbc_images_scraper_test'
url = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk'

# Function to parse link anchors for images
def img_links_parser(url, links_list):
    res = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = bs(res,'lxml')
    content = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'top-story__image'})

    for i in content:
        try:
            link = i.attrs['style']
            # Pulling the anchor from parentheses
            link = link[link.find('(')+1 : link.find(')')]
            # Putting the anchor in the list of links
            links_list.append(link)
        except:
            # links might be under 'data-lazy' attribute w/o paranthesis
            links_list.append(i.attrs['data-lazy'])

# Function to load images from links
def img_loader(base_url, links_list, path_location):
    for link in links_list:
        try:
            # Pulling last element off the link which is name.jpg
            file_name = link.split('/')[-1]
            # Following the link and saving content in a given direcotory
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(urllib.parse.urljoin(base_url, link), 
            os.path.join(path_location, file_name))
        except:
            print('Error on {}'.format(urllib.parse.urljoin(base_url, link)))
```

The following code is split up in to two cases:

Case 1: I'm using multiple threads:

```
threads = []
t1 = threading.Thread(target = img_loader, args = (url, links[:10], path))
t2 = threading.Thread(target = img_loader, args = (url, links[10:20], path))
t3 = threading.Thread(target = img_loader, args = (url, links[20:30], path))
t4 = threading.Thread(target = img_loader, args = (url, links[30:40], path))
t5 = threading.Thread(target = img_loader, args = (url, links[40:50], path))
t6 = threading.Thread(target = img_loader, args = (url, links[50:], path))

threads.extend([t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6])
for t in threads:
    t.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

The above code does its job on my machine for 10 seconds.

Case 2: I'm using `ThreadPoolExecutor`

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(50) as exec:
    results = exec.submit(img_loader, url, links, path)
```

The above code results to 18 seconds.

My understanding was that `ThreadPoolExecutor` creates a thread for each worker. So, given I set `max_workers` to 50 would result to 50 threads and therefore should have completed the job faster.

Can someone please explain what am I missing here? I admit that I'm making a silly mistake here but I just don't get it.

Many thanks!

Comment: as @hansaplast noted I was using just one worker. So I just altered my `img_loader` function to accept a single link and then added a `for` loop beneath the context manager to process each link in the list. And it reduced time down to 3.8s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Case 2 you're sending all the links to one worker. Instead of

```
exec.submit(img_loader, url, links, path)
```

you'd need to:

```
for link in links:
    exec.submit(img_loader, url, [link], path)
```

I didn't try it out myself, that's just from [reading the documentation of ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example)

Comment: yes, you're absolutely right. I don't know why didn't I try that out myself though I had thinking about that too. Thanks a lot for coming back to me! The result is 3.8 seconds which is cool! :)

Comment: @Vlad, can you add a proper answer to your question. What is the difference between `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` vs `threading`?

Answer (score 1):

Following this explanation from this [link](https://www.toptal.com/python/beginners-guide-to-concurrency-and-parallelism-in-python) you could also use the executor.map function instead of running a for loop as suggested by hansaplast.

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:

    # Create a new partially applied function that stores the directory
    # argument.
    # 
    # This allows the download_link function that normally takes two
    # arguments to work with the map function that expects a function of a
    # single argument.
    fn = partial(download_link, download_dir)

    # Executes fn concurrently using threads on the links iterable. The
    # timeout is for the entire process, not a single call, so downloading
    # all images must complete within 30 seconds.
    executor.map(fn, links, timeout=30)
```

I think it can be easily adapted to your needs.

And answering the question about threadpoolexecutor, I am not an expert on it, but as per the documentation I've read so far ThreadPoolExecutor is a simpler way to create a dynamic pool of workers than using Threading.Thread by yourself.